# Using jqGrid can you freeze columns using a subgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using a subgrid and trying to freeze 2 columns - is this possible? If I remove the subgrid then the freezing columns work correctly.

My jQuery code is:

```
jQuery("#list11").jqGrid({ 
        url:'activity_grid.php?q=1', 
        datatype: "xml", 
        height: 300, 
        width:300,
        colNames:['Retailer','Objective', 'Total', 'Period'], 
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'Retailer',index:'Retailer', width:55, frozen : true}, 
            {name:'Objective',index:'Objective', width:90, frozen : true}, 
            {name:'Total',index:'Total', width:100}, 
            {name:'Period',index:'Period', width:80, align:"right"}
        ], 
        viewrecords: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        subGrid : true, 
        subGridUrl: 'subgrid.php?q=2', 
        subGridModel: [{ 
                name : ['No','Item','Qty','Unit','Line Total'], 
                width : [55,200,80,80,80] 
            } ] 
    }); 

$("#list11").jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, here is a full list of features with which you can't set up frozen columns:

- TreeGrid
- SubGrid
- Cell Editing
- Inline Editing (the frozen columns can not be edited)
- Sortable Columns
- Virtual Scrolling
- Data Grouping